# How to encode characters in a tweet to integers by using python

Tags: python, twitter, encoding

I read a file that contains tweet per line by using python. Now, I need to create a character vocabulary from it and encode each sentence by using it. However, I need to extract the emoji descriptions without dividing them to characters. To make my purpose more clear lets think the following tweet:

```
x='Wish she could have told me herself. @NicoleScherzy #nicolescherzinger #OneLove #myfav #MyQueen :heavy_black_heart:\xef\xb8\x8f:heavy_black_heart:\xef\xb8\x8f'
```

First of all, I should say that, I don't know why there are two `\xef\xb8\x8f` . When I look at the file, there aren't such things.

Let's say I have a dictionary that stores an unique integer for each character and emoji description `(:heavy_black_heart:)` :

```
dict = {'W => 1' , 'i=>2','s=>3','h=>4',':heavy_black_heart =>5',':smiling_face=>6','z=>7', .... etc}
```

Now, what I want to do is convert this X string to Y array that stores corresponding integers for each characters and emoji descriptions in the string.

```
Y= [1,2,3,4,......,5,5]
```

I read the file, put it into array but I couldn't find how could I make the last part. Here is what I've done so far:

```
def parse_dataset(fp):
    y = []
    corpus = []
    with open(fp, 'rt') as data_in:
        for line in data_in:
            if not line.startswith("Tweet index"): # discard first line if it contains metadata
                line = line.rstrip() # remove trailing whitespace
                label = int(line.split("\t")[1])
                tweet = line.split("\t")[2]
                y.append(label)
                corpus.append(tweet)
    return corpus, y

if __name__ == "__main__":
     DATASET_FP = "input_file.txt"
    corpus, y = parse_dataset(DATASET_FP)
```

Is there anybody who can help me ?

Comment: The syntax for your dictionary is strange, almost Ruby.  If you use that syntax in Python you will get a `set`.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @cdarke I wrote it as pseudocode to make things faster. Please ignore the sytax for dictionary. It should also contains all chars seen in the corpus

Comment: So do you want to parse the string X looking for each key in the dictionary?

Comment: Yes, but at first, I should also create that dictionary from the corpus. It should contain all the characters exist in file and also all emoji descriptions in the file. Syntax for the Emoji description is as in the example `:description_name:` @cdarke